# Convert console/empty project to a Win32 project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I originally started a project in Visual C++ 2010, which was an empty/Blank project. How do I convert this to a Win32 project so that there is no console ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the `/SUBSYSTEM` setting under linker options.

[image]

Be sure to get both the Debug and Release configurations (or, leave the console enabled for Debug builds and send some useful information there)

Comment: And I should set that to Windows ? My ultimate aim is to create a background app with no window whatsoever. I created one with a terminal, just for debugging.

Comment: @viraj: Yep.  An app using `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` doesn't have any UI unless it creates some windows.